# Set Sessionstate cookieless="true" in asp .Net, is the sessions state maintained?

Tags: asp.net

How can the session state be maintained in asp.Net, if the cookies are turned off in browser or `cookieless="true"` is added within `sessionmode` tags in web.config?

The following tag shows `cookieless="true"` in web.config.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"
  cookieless="true"
  timeout="30"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASP.NET framework inserts a `unique id` to the URL, you can check this by disabling the cookie or by setting the `cookieless` attribute to `true` as you did.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.140).aspx):-

> By default, the SessionID value is stored in a non-expiring session
>   cookie in the browser.

If you specify `cookieless="true"` then:

> ASP.NET maintains cookieless session state by automatically inserting
>   a unique session ID into the page's URL.

Comment: Hey Rahul, In the case of sessionId saved in cookies is it a persistent or non persistent cookie? In MSDN it is specified as persistent right?

Comment: @MGeorge - Yes, Session cookies will be persistent by default and its default time is 20 minutes.

Comment: is unique session ID in the page's URL safe? I mean to keep  cookieless="true" has any drawback??

Answer (score 2):

Answer is yes, it will still maintain session via URL. It will attach unique identifier for session to URL, that unique identifier is stored in cookie for cookieless = false.

URL will look like this - `http://yourserver/folder/(session ID here)/default.aspx`

Live example -

> http://localhost:2677/WebSite1/(S(3abhbgwjg33aqrt3uat2kh4d))/cookielesssessiondetection.aspx

Here `3abhbgwjg33aqrt3uat2kh4d` is session id.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's worth still doing this so that Session variables with work in IE. I imagine people still use IE in 2020 but I don't know why.