# ASP.NET MVC strange routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am faced with strange behavior in routing. On the example of the any site:

```
https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/net/
https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/(X(1)S(03n5gkj4gj0rtg1pvxg0mswn)))/products/net/
https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/(X(1)S(1)))/products/net/
```

give the same result.

What are the weird segments of the form `X(1)S(1)`?
How to disable such routing? And is it necessary to do this?

Another example:

```
https://www.kentico.com/customers/customer-projects
https://www.kentico.com/(X(1)S(1))/customers/customer-projects
```

Comment: Check your `webconfig`, does this include `<sessionState cookieless="true"
     regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />` under `<system.web>` section?

Comment: no, this is wrong

Comment: most possibly this is the cause with your session settings under `webconfig` which now including unique session identifier per request.

Comment: comment out or remove those 2 lines (if you have) and  Add `<sessionState timeout="60" cookieless="false" mode="InProc"></sessionState>` in your `<system.web>` section  and check whether its now working or not.

Comment: <sessionState cookieName="_contSiteCookie_" mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=xxx.xxx.141.124:42424" />

 </system.web>

Comment: try with `cookieless="false"` in our current `sessionState`. i,e: `<sessionState cookieName="contSiteCookie" mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" stateConnectionString="tcpip=xxx.xxx.141.124:42424" />`

Comment: @АлександрШабунин Can you ensure that ASP.NET State service is running on the specified IP address machine or is it your local IP address? Try changing it to 127.0.0.1 and ensure ASP.NET State service is running locally

Comment: [stackoverflaw link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233287/set-sessionstate-cookieless-true-in-asp-net-is-the-sessions-state-maintained) you can lookup once regarding you problem.

Comment: so, thanks, I will sort this out